# script db_dump using .pgpass on private RDS Instance

Tags: postgresql, shell, amazon-rds

I have a Postgres RDS instance in a private subnet in my VPC. I use a VPN on an EC2 instance to connect from my local machine (Windows 11). I have a batch file with three different db_dump commands

pg_dump.bat

```
pg_dump -h rds_enpoint -U myuser -p 5432 -d db_1_name > C:\<path to db_1_dump.dump>

pg_dump -h rds_enpoint -U myuser -p 5432 -d db_2_name > C:\<path to db_2_dump.dump>

pg_dump -h rds_enpoint -U myuser -p 5432 -d db_3_name > C:\<path to db_3_dump.dump>
```

I want to execute this batch in a python script that pushes the .dump files to an s3 bucket (I can do this). When I execute pg_dump.bat, I have to enter the password for each command to execute.

I've been trying to figure out how to store the [password file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) on my local Windows machine.

I've created the pgpass.conf file in app data

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\postgresql\postgresql.conf
```

with this

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

It still asks me for the password.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\username> pg_dump -h res_endpoint -U username -p 5432 -d db_1_name > C:\<path to db_1_dump.dump
>>
Password:
```

When I try to bypass the password

```
pg_dump -h res_endpoint -U username -p 5432 -d db_1_name -w > C:\<path to db_1_dump.dump

pg_dump: error: connection to server at "rds_endpoint" (ip), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

What am I doing wrong? I know there's a way to store a .pgpass file on the user's home directory. However, I don't know how to SSH into an rds instance and add a file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the name of the file wrong, and are missing an element of the path.

It will generally be:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf
```

Also, make sure the line endings in the file are not \r\n, as the \r will be considered part of the password.